# iPad book / cartoon contents plus Marvel like cartoons

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to create and sell book / cartoons by individual episodes.

What's the best way to to this? iBook from the apple store tends to sell by entire volume / book... I see an App from Marvel sells its contents by individual episodes, but I don't want to create / maintain shopping carts and stuff. (I am assuming iPad / iPhone users are downloading each cartoon episodes by their Marvel servers)  I want to utilize Apple iBook / iTune store...

Second questions: Is Marvel-like cartoons all jpg pictures showing frame by frame?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the in-app purchase feature to unlock content / purchase credits, but you will still need to either have a server containing all the content or provide the content with the application itself.

The Marvel cartoons probably use either a proprietary format to facilitate appropriate scrolling and zooming while reading, or use a PDF with an additional instruction set. In general the choice is yours.